# Pandas dataframe left align data

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

How do I set the data within a dataframe to be left-aligned?

I'm using python 2.7.13.

This question has been asked before but the accepted answer didn't even work.
The answer given was:

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

It doesn't work, my data is still right aligned.

Does anyone know how? Do I have to import any modules other than pandas?

Comment: Where do you use it and how? If you are using it for printing, you need to run it on Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Java Oxygen to run the entire thing, and I just want to leave it as code. Is there any way, outside of this style.set way, to align all data in the dataframe to the left?

Comment: @Clarence based on your comments I think you need the solution in case2 of my answer below. Have a look..

Answer (score -1):

#### Case 1: Styling to print as html

`df.style.set_properties` returns an object of type `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler`

```
type(df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'}))
Out[37]: pandas.io.formats.style.Styler
```

Which is meant to be rendered as an html string as follows:

```
s = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
s.render()
```

Then you can use the result of `s.render()` in your `HTML` file.

---

#### Case 2: Align data left as a dataframe

If you are looking for a way to remove left whitespaces from the values in your dataFrame and leave the data within a dataframe, here's an example on how to do that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[' a','    b'],['  c', '  d']], columns=list('AB'))
df = df.stack().str.lstrip().unstack()
```

output:

```
   A  B
0  a  b
1  c  d
```